# Куча синтаксических ошибок при переносе сайта с локального сервера на хост

Tags: хостинг

Перенес файлы на хост с локального сервера, в папку `html-public`, создал бд и поменял в коде конэкшэны, но пишет куча синтаксических ошибок, которых при локальном доступе не было.

Подскажите что не так, что я упустил? Первый раз пытаюсь залить проект на хост. Хост `hostinger`, если это имеет значение.

Например ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /home/u889389547/public_html/core/route.php on line 1

Мысль на то что нужно изменить .htacces, сейчас там следующий код:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**Обновление**
Хост стал нормально считывать файлы и даже вывел стартовую страницу, но с ошибкой:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of Controller_Main::action_index() should be compatible with Controller::action_index()

Как решить?

Comment: Текст ошибок нам самим придумать нужно?

Comment: Сравните вывод phpinfo на хостинге и на локальном компьютере. Возможно понадобится поменять версию PHP или установить (через ТП хостинга) какие-то модули.

Comment: @Денис ещё возможно, что у вас где-то в файлах был указан абсолютный путь при подключении другого файла. На хостинге он, разумеется, будет другим. Поэтому если абсолютные пути у вас где-то указаны - замените их на относительные.

Comment: У меня сайт на hostinger, если есть include или другие подключения начинающиеся с /, то фигарь полный путь /public_html/путь до скрипта.php

Comment: насчет PHP версии, стоит такая же как и на локальном, везде относительные ссылки. Вот щас вообще начало выдавать ошибку 500,

Comment: @МаксимДробышев сейчас попробовал, к сожалению не могу понять помогло или нет, так как ошибка 500 никуда не пропала.

Comment: @Денис: причины ошибки 500 указаны в журнале ошибок сервера. Записи из него хостеры как правило выводят в панели управления.

Comment: /home/u196274469/public_html вот так полная ссылка выглядит.